# sed append/Insert words between patterns

Tags: regex, awk, sed, pattern-matching

I have file contain following:

```
%_libdir/%name/mod_abstraction.so
%_libdir/%name/mod_alsa.so
%_libdir/%name/mod_avmd.so
%_libdir/%name/mod_amr.so
%_libdir/%name/mod_b64.so
%_libdir/%name/mod_blacklist.so
%_libdir/%name/mod_bv.so
%_libdir/%name/mod_callcenter.so
%_libdir/%name/mod_cidlookup.so
%_libdir/%name/mod_cdr_csv.so
%_libdir/%name/mod_cdr_mongodb.so
%_libdir/%name/mod_cdr_sqlite.so
%_libdir/%name/mod_cdr_pg_csv.so
%_libdir/%name/mod_celt.so
%_libdir/%name/mod_cluechoo.so
%_libdir/%name/mod_codec2.so
%_libdir/%name/mod_commands.so
%_libdir/%name/mod_conference.so
%_libdir/%name/mod_console.so
%_libdir/%name/mod_curl.so
```

I want to add following extra directory `mod` in above path so it will look like following:

```
%_libdir/%name/mod/mod_abstraction.so
%_libdir/%name/mod/mod_alsa.so
%_libdir/%name/mod/mod_avmd.so
%_libdir/%name/mod/mod_amr.so
...
...
```

I know we can use `sed` but i am not expert, i tried many combo but didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
sed -i.bak 's~mod_~mod/&~' file
```

Or else:

```
sed -i.bak 's~%name/~&mod/~' file
```

Comment: Thanks, i also found solution but anyway i will select your answer you where first!!

Answer (score 0):

I also found solution:

```
 sed -i 's/mod/\mod\/&/' filename
```